# LaTex - Is it possible to display nice equations, and normal text together while using display(Math())?

Tags: python, latex, jupyter, f-string

Can I print normal text while using display(Math()) with F-string?

I would like to use F-string and mix it with nice equations, but I can't figure out how to print normal text. As you can see in the first image the text isn't normal(font). I also had to add \ after each string in order to create a space.

I have tried some options like \text, \text{} \, etc... but it doesn't work with F-string.

I'm using Jupyter if it helps.

**Thank you!**

```
display(Math(f"Press\ '1'\ to\ compute\ {x}^{y}\ or\ '2'\ to\ compute\\frac{x}{y}"))
```

[image: How to change this to normal font?]

[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: Is this Jupyter? If so, please add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-bracket the brackets you normally use with `\text{}` and add in using Python's raw string in combination with your f-string (based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/display-command-output-as-math-ipython-display-math/3125/3?u=fomightez)):

```py
from IPython.display import Math
x = 2
y = 4
Math(rf'\text{{Press 1 to compute }} {x}^{y} \text{{or 2 to compute }} \frac{x}{y}')
```

Actual display with formatting shown:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of "raw"

Comment: Yes, it is one of those very useful things that is hard to find until you learn about it. It often comes up when dealing with paths on Windows-based machines. Or with regular expressions. [This looks like a good intro](https://blog.devgenius.io/beauty-of-raw-strings-in-python-fa627d674cbf) that I probably should have included.

Answer (score -1):

You may find this [Latexify library](https://pypi.org/project/latexify-py/) helpful! You should be able to generate clean Latex descriptions from your function definitions.

Comment: Hi @EthanCloin,
It's not what I'm looking for... thanks anyway.